# Conexao externa ao sql server por aplicativo android, C# xamarim

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin

Bom estou em busca de informações a respeito de qual o procedimento para acessar uma base de dados sql server pelo android.

Comment: E ai Daniel, beleza? Seja bem vindo ao SO Pt. A sua pergunta é um pouco vaga. Altere sua pergunta dizendo oque você já pesquisou e tentou, fica mais fácil para te ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No caso de aplicativos mobile a conexão com banco de dados é um pouco diferente da que é feita com aplicações desktop.

Para você "conversar" com o banco de dados por meio de um aplicativo é necessário você criar um servidor, que fará a intermediação entre o banco e o aplicativo. No caso o servidor teria que ficar junto ao banco de dados.

Pelo aplicativo você fará requisições ao servidor que executará a ação requisitada, por exemplo:

• Se você quer buscar dados (SELECT) você teria que criar uma rotina (GET) no servidor que irá se conectar ao banco, realizar a pesquisa e depois retornar os dados da sua pesquisa, aconselho retornar os dados em forma JSON, e então no aplicativo você trata este JSON.

• Se você quer inserir dados (INSERT) você teria que criar uma rotina (POST) no servidor que irá receber os dados do aplicativo e então se conectar ao banco, realizar o insert e depois retornar para seu aplicativo se deu tudo certo ou não, outra vez aconselho enviar os dados para o servidor utilizando JSON.

Obs.: Aconselho utilizar JSON por ser uma forma leve de transitar os dados e porque todas as linguagem aceitam.

Você pode criar um serviço no windows que funcionará como um servidor, utilizando C#, Pascal (Delphi), PHP, entre outros... Procure por algo como Web Service RESTFULL com JSON na linguagem que você melhor entenda.

Comment: Resolvido eu encontrei conteúdos que me deram uma caminho ate a solução, pode fechar o tópico rsrs